# Is it possible to iterate over 2 different inputs inside a foreach in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So what I am trying to do is identify if a file is present in a folder, if not copy it. The current structure uses a GetMetadata activity from the source, passes that list to a foreach activity, I am trying to add another GetMetadata activity inside the foreach for the destination then do a NOT filter based on the 'contains' expression to check if the item from the metadata activity for source is present in the childitems from the metadata activity in the destination, question is how do I distinguish these to item() when running in the filter activity, is it possible to access these as different objects?

Comment: we could parameter the filename in the dataset, add filed list: exists.  Then using If-condition to filter the file. Just confused that if the file not exist, how to copy it??

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try it out, what I meant was if file does not exist in the destination, then copy it from source

Comment: I got it! Let me try and share you the example!

Comment: Hi @Ashish Singh, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Ashish Singh, do you have any other concerns? Please feel free and let us know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow my steps:

**1. Create Source/Sink dataset with parameter 'SourceFile'/SinkFile:**

Source dataset:

[image]

Sink dataset:
[image]

**2. Set pipeline parameter 'filename':**
[image]

**3. Get metadata settings:**

Get metadata 1:

[image]

Get metadata 1:

[image]

**4. If condition settings:**

Using bellow expression to filter: if the file is exist in Source and not in Sink:

```
@and(equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists,false),equals(activity('Get Metadata2').output.exists,true))
```

[image]

**5. Set the true active:**

If the file is exist in Source and not in Sink, copy the file to Sink:

[image]